# Prove that for all $n$ there exist positive integers $x_1, ..., x_n$ such that $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + ... + \frac{1}{nx_n} = 1$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Prove that for all $n$ there exist positive integers $x_1, ..., x_n$ such that $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + ... + \frac{1}{nx_n} = 1$

I actually managed to write a short proof, but I'd appreciate it if someone could check it for me and offer some feedback. I'm not very used to induction so I'm not sure the proof is very clear or correct. Hope that's appropriate for this forum!

My intuition was that starting with $n = 2 \rightarrow\frac{1}{1\times2} + \frac{1}{2\times1} = 1$ you can always add one more term by making $x_n = n + 1$ and $x_{n+1} = 1$, such as in

$\frac{1}{1\times2} + \frac{1}{2\times1} = \frac{1}{1\times2} + \frac{1}{2\times3} + \frac{1}{3\times1} = \frac{1}{1\times2} + \frac{1}{2\times3} + \frac{1}{3\times4} + \frac{1}{4\times1}$ = ... = 1

So here's the proof:

**Statement:** for all $n$ there exist positive integers $x_1, ..., x_n$ such that $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + ... + \frac{1}{nx_n} = 1$

**Proof (by induction)**:
   **Base case**:
     For $n = 1$, we have that $\frac{1}{x_1} = 1$ for $x_1 = 1$

**Inductive step**:
     If for some $n$:
     $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + … + \frac{1}{nx_n} = 1$, for certain $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$
     and we also have that $x_n = 1$

It follows that:
     $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + … + \frac{1}{n} = 1$

$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + … + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$

$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + … + \frac{n + 1 - n}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$

$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{2x_2} + … + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$

Therefore, if $y_i = x_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, $y_n = n + 1$ and $y_{n+1} = 1$, it follows that:

$\frac{1}{y_1} + \frac{1}{2y_2} + … + \frac{1}{ny_n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)y_{n+1}}= 1$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could simply define $x_k = \frac{n}{k}$ for $1 \le k \le n$.

Comment: "and we also have that $x_n=1$"? How do you know that?

Comment: What are the restrictions on $x_i$?  If we let $x_1, ..., x_{n-1}$ be any non-zero we want we just have to set $x_n = \frac 1{n(1-(\frac 1{x_1} + .... + \frac 1{(n-1)x_{n-1}}))}$.  Do they have to be the *same* set of $x_i$ for all $n$? Which ... is clearly impossible as if $\frac 1{x_1} + \frac 1{2x_2} =1$ then $\frac 1{x_1} + \frac 1{2x_2} +\frac 1{3x_3} \ne 0$.

Comment: @fleablood The order of quantifiers clearly specify that the set of $x_i$ doesn't have to be the same for all $n$. "**for  all** $n$ **there exists** $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$".

Comment: @delta_phi From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **The title is not the first sentence of your question**

Comment: @jjagmath  But there has to be *SOME* restriction on the $x_i$.  Otherwise the question is utterly trivial. I just figured if it had to be the same set that was the only way to make the question at all interesting.  .....But of course it's very easy to show that would be impossible.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I forgot to mention the  $x_n$ are supposed to be positive integers. I suppose that's the most important part. I'm really sorry for that and I'll edit that in.

As for why $x_n = 1$ I wasn't sure how to word that, but it is true for the base case, and if it is true for case $n$ it is true for case $n+1$ following the steps mentioned. I suppose that means I could prove the stronger statement "show that for all positive integers n, there exist positive integers $x_1,...,x_n$ that satisfy the sum with the additional condition that $x_n=1$

Comment: Once you add that additional condition ($x_n=1$) to the statement, your proof is right. This is a very nice example where proving something stronger allows the induction to work.

Comment: By the way, since you already found an easy pattern that works, you could prove the even more stronger statement that is actually easier to prove by induction $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I should edit the question with this change or leave it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is correct, but you do not need induction.
You suggested that $\frac{1}{2*1}+\frac{1}{3*2}+...+ \frac{1}{n(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n}=1$. This is true: the sum is $\frac11-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+....+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}=1$

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it does look way more concise like this